# jQuery show same value grabbed from different data attributes

Tags: jquery

I put 2 same data attributes in multiple elements (data-product-name & data-product-code), the intention is to populate the value from the data attribute in some input field.

```
<strong class="displayed_product_name" data-product-name="All content" data-product-code="abc">All content</strong>
```

I grab the data attributes values and make them as an array.

```
var arrProductCode = [];
$(this).closest('.each_content_item').find('[data-product-code]').each(function () {
    arrProductCode.push($(this).text());
});

var arrProductName = [];
$(this).closest('.each_content_item').find('[data-product-name]').each(function () {
    arrProductName.push($(this).text());
});
```

To populate them in element and an input field

```
$(arrProductName).each(function () {
    $('.pop_edit_country').find('.pop_edit_product_list ul').append("<li>" + this + "</li>");
});
$(arrProductCode).each(function () {
    $('.hidden_edit_country_product_list').val($('.hidden_edit_country_product_list').val() + arrProductCode + ',');
});
```

The value of data-product-name grabbed correctly, but why the value of data-product-code is the same as data-product-name? I couldn't solve it, is it because 1 element cannot contain 2 data attributes?

Comment: Could you show the full html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the both case you call `text` function instead of calling `data` function.

`text` function get the text context of your element while `data` function gets the content of `data attribute` you passed to it.

Here is the corrected code:

```
var arrProductCode = [];
$(this).closest('.each_content_item').find('[data-product-code]').each(function () {
    arrProductCode.push($(this).data('product-code'));
});

var arrProductName = [];
$(this).closest('.each_content_item').find('[data-product-name]').each(function () {
    arrProductName.push($(this).data('product-name'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks ADreNaLiNe-DJ, you just saved my days.